# Making a simple integral list with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, nodes

I'm trying to create a basic integral list made with Nodes (I should also point that I'm learning pointers by doing this exercise)

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Every time I tried to print the list it shows me random value
Here's my code:

```
Node *head = NULL;  // The head of the list - global


void push(int d) {

    Node newNode;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("In\n");
        head = &newNode;
        (*head).data = d;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("In2");
        newNode.next = head;
        head = &newNode;
    }

void printList() {
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("In while\n");
        printf("%d",(*head).data);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

when I try to do for example: `push(1);`
and `printList()`
I get: `263958281` or any other random value.
Does anyone knows why ?

PS: If I tried to do:

```
push(1);
push(2);
printList();
```

my ideal output would be:

```
2 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That:

```
Node newNode;
```

Allocates the node on the stack. After the function returns that node exists no more.

List nodes are normally allocated from the heap with [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) function. Heap-allocated memory persists until it is explicitly deallocated with [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free).

E.g.:

```
void push(int d) {
    Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = d;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps know how could I do in order to keep it ?

Comment: @MM1 Added an example for you.

Comment: Can you explain why did you need to allocate memory in order for it to work ? So that we can keep the node "alive" when the functions returns ?

Comment: @MM1 Explained.

Comment: @MM1 In production code you need to check for `malloc` errors and use `free` to deallocate memory when it is no longer needed.